J5 - Admin - New Button not opening form
Here's my conundrum.  My component has several elements and in the admin side lists of each element I have a standard "New" button to create a new record for that element.  All my lists work bar 1 which happens to be the default list for the component.
So if I have a blank list, ie no records showing in the list, I click the New button and nothing happens.  If I change the filter to show a list with a status of say Archived (of which I have a couple of records), then the list is not empty as you would expect, and then when I click the new button, the form opens as expected for me to create a new record.  Once I save that record, then remove the filter so it just displays published and unpublished records, then the new button works as it should.
Here is a snippet of my View Tmpl file in my addTemplate function.
$toolbar = Toolbar::getInstance('toolbar');

$canDo = ContentHelper::getActions('com_mycomponent','component',0);

ToolbarHelper::title(Text::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_TITLE_POSITIONS'), 'positions.png');

$toolbar->link('JTOOLBAR_DASHBOARD', 'index.php?option=com_cpanel&view=cpanel&dashboard=mycomponent');

if ($canDo->get('core.create')) {
    $toolbar->addNew('position.add');
}

if ($canDo->get('core.edit.state')) {
    $dropdown = $toolbar->dropdownButton('status-group')
        ->text('JTOOLBAR_CHANGE_STATUS')
        ->toggleSplit(false)
        ->icon('fa fa-ellipsis-h')
        ->buttonClass('btn btn-info')
        ->listCheck(true);

    $childBar = $dropdown->getChildToolbar();
    $childBar->publish('positions.publish')->listCheck(true);
    $childBar->unpublish('positions.unpublish')->listCheck(true);
    $childBar->archive('positions.archive')->listCheck(true);
    $childBar->checkin('positions.checkin')->listCheck(true);

    if ($this->state->get('filter.state') != -2) {
        $childBar->trash('positions.trash')->listCheck(true);
    }
}

As always, any guidance appreciated.

I found the problem although if anyone can explain why this is the case I would appreciate it.  It was because I had an if statement around the table in the template display file as follows:
<form action="<?php echo Route::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=positions'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
    <div id="j-main-container" class="j-main-container">

        <?php echo LayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default', array('view' => $this)); ?>

        <?php if (empty($this->items)) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <span class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only"><?php echo Text::_('INFO'); ?></span>
                <?php echo Text::_('JGLOBAL_NO_MATCHING_RESULTS'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <table class="table table-striped" id="positionList">

So once I moved this if statement to be wrapped around the "foreach", then the New button worked fine.  As it turns out I don't need this alert display anyway, so I'll be removing it entirely.  Cheers.

It doesn't make a lot of sense that the New button is rendered but is not responsive to being clicked unless it is outside the if section.. I would want to see more code around where the toolbar is rendered and maybe a breakpoint in position->add() to check if it is in fact reaching that method but failing silently.

Hmmm I agree that it doesn't make sense, when I get a moment I'll revisit this to see if I can identify the cause.
